# Get all days between tomorrow and 60 days forward then loop through them

Tags: java, date, loops

I need to take tomorrow, add 60 days to it and loop over it day by day. Just wondering what would be the appropriate way of doing this?

This is what I tried. Somehow it starts my loop month back and in January 2015 it shows month as 0.

```
    Calendar startCalemder = Calendar.getInstance();
    startCalemder.setTime(new Date());
    startCalemder.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

    Calendar endCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    endCalendar.setTime(new Date());
    endCalendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 60);

    //loop over day by day
    for (; startCalemder.compareTo(endCalendar) <= 0;
            startCalemder.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)) {
        startCalemder.get(Calendar.YEAR); //shows year
        startCalemder.get(Calendar.MONTH); //shows month
        startCalemder.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); //shows day
    }
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27019788/get-all-days-from-tomorrow-and-two-months-forward-and-loop-through-them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is alright. What you need to understand about the crazy `Calendar` API is that 0 means January and 10 means November.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.JANUARY

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, except that it's not necessary to invoke `setTime(new Date())` when you immediately before create a new Calendar with `Calendar.getInstance()`, which already gives you a new Calendar instance set to the current time.

Answer (score -1):

As a side answer, using the excellent [Joda](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library:

```
DateTime start = new Datime().plusDays(1);
DateTime end = start.plusDays(60);
for(DateTime current = start ; current.isBefore(end) ; 
        current = current.plusDays(1)) {
    int year = current.getYear();
    int month = current.getMonthOfYear();
    int day = current.getDayOfMonth();
}
```

Comment: Why downvote? I am just providing an alternative answer to people having the same question. No problem for not accepting, but why downvote?